# Where are the emoji *category* icons stored on OSX?

Tags: macos, emoji

The emoji picker on OSX has a series of "category" icons, which emoji are grouped by:

[image]

Do you know where those can be found? I looked in the system icons directory, `/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/`, and couldn't find them there.

I then used Font Book to look at all of the symbols in the Apple Color Emoji font, and I couldn't find them there, either.

Are there other common places that Apple stores resources for apps? Do you know where these things are stored?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icons are stored as PDF and TIFF files in the resources for the character palette:

```
/System/Library/Input Methods/CharacterPalette.app/Contents/Resources/
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'm pretty surprised at how low quality the .tiffs seem to be...yet I swapped them, and it did swap them in the UI, so I guess that says something.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I compared the rendered ones to the .tiffs, and they do seem to be of higher quality. Am I missing something here? Check out a zoomed-in screenshot here: https://cloudup.com/cEfV5PY86Mn

Comment: @jmeas Ah, I've had a look in both `/System/Library/Input Methods/CharacterPalette.app/` and `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CharacterPicker.framework/` but I can't find anything else. These are the two places which refer to the two different apps where these icons are used. Feel free to have a look through yourself, I'm having another look through now too.

Comment: Thanks for the additional links. I've been taking a look, and haven't found anything yet. The strangest thing is that replacing the tiffs does seem to replace the icon in the menu, which does suggest that those ARE the images being used. Very odd!

Comment: @jmeas I had a moment of inspiration, they're TIFF files, and each contains two different resolution images! Both 1x and 2x are included in each of the TIFF files, see edit.

Comment: Niiiiice! I had no idea that .tiff files worked that way. Thanks, @grgarside!